Код с модулем progress не работает
Установил через pip; стандартный код из примера не работает из-за from progress.bar
from progress.bar import Bar

bar = Bar('Processing', max=20)
for i in range(20):
    # Do some work
    bar.next()
bar.finish()


Добро пожаловать на сайт, NeS, ознакомьтесь пожалуйста со справкой как задать вопрос на ru.SO https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

вы предлагаете сыграть в игру "Угадай какая ошибка у автора вопроса"?


Как именно устанавливали? Покажите код, который запускали для установки. 2) Что значит "не работает", с какими признаками? Разъясните прямо в вопросе.


Немножко измените ваш код, например так:
import time
from progress.bar import Bar

with Bar('Processing', max=20) as bar:
    for i in range(20):
        time.sleep(.2)    # Do some work
        bar.next()

и он будет работать:


Объяснение:
В вашем примере нет кода для какой-то длинной работы, только комментарий
    # Do some work

(по-русски «делай какую-то работу»).
Таким образом весь цикл for (т.е. его 20 итераций) выполнится мгновенно, через несколько микросекунд,  а вы не увидите никакого постепенного прогресса работы.
Я симулировал длинную работу задержкой 0.2 секунды (200 миллисекунд) применением функции sleep(.2) («спи 0.2 секунд») из стандартного модуля time.
